# Can Jmeter LDAP Request or LDAP Extended Request populate a multi-valued attribute?

Tags: jmeter, ldap

I am working on a Jmeter LDAP test plan and the test plan has to populate an attribute on the LDAP that is multi-valued.

When I do an LDAP search sampler, I noted that the value I get back is a string, with the values separated by ", ".

But, if I take the same comma-separated string and try to do an LDAP modify or add, using either an LDAP Request or LDAP Extended Request, I get an error.

So I am wondering if there is a way that the Jmeter LDAP Request or LDAP Extended Request can do that?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT: When I try to use an Extended LDAP Request modification test/add with the attribute of "", I get this error in the Jmeter GUI response:

```
When attempting to modify entry cn=xxx... to replace the set of values for attribute lastlogindate, value "20181023085627-04, 20181024063205-04" was found to be invalid according to the associated syntax:  The provided value "20181023085627-04, 20181024063205-04" is not a valid generalized time value because it contains an invalid character '-' at position 14
```

The strange part is that even though I have Jmeter to log at debug level, I don't see any detail on the error in the Jmeter.log, but/so I am guessing that that error message is coming from the Jmeter client itself.  I noticed that the message says:

```
to replace the set of values
```

so it seems like it recognizes that I am trying to modify/replace a multi-value, but it doesn't seem to like the syntax of the replacement values string(s).

Does anyone know what the correct format SHOULD be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question, or at least "A" answer:  It appears that I can use an Extended LDAP request, and add the same attribute in that request, multiple times. So for example, if I am populating an attribute named "foo" the Extended LDAP request would have the following:

```
attribute  value  opcode
foo        12345  add
foo        12346  add
etc.
```

I think I also need to do a replace with no value, to empty the attribute, before all the adds.